# Clicar e alterar textos dentro do elemento

Tags: javascript, html

Dando uma pesquisada eu encontrei o `contenteditable`, mas queria saber se existe outra forma para isso, dando uma olhada em alguns construtores de sites que usam esse tipo de coisa, acho que nenhum usava o `contenteditable`, já que não vi o atributo em nenhum elemento de toda a página.

Comment: Já tentou fazer usar InnerHTML com o id do elemento?

Comment: Olha esse link: https://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/

Comment: Sugiro que olhe a biblioteca am angular: angular-xeditable
Ë uma das maneiras de se fazer o que deseja.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As formas que eu consigo pensar são as seguintes:

1. `contenteditable=true`
2. Ao clicar, converter para um `input`ou `textarea` (o linkedin faz assim)
3. Fazer um esquema em JavaScript onde ele coloque um elemento em cima, esconda o anterior e passe o valor para o elemento inicial via innerHTML.